# Unable to add Metadata to PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm writing a small application for creating specific PDFs.

Now I wanted to add a Metadata stream in order to get it PDF/A conform.
But as soon as I do so, my PDF seems to have an error, and veraPDF shows me the error

`Exception: Couldn't parse stream caused by exception: PDFParser::GetXRefSection(...)can not locate xref table`

I don't know what is wrong with my PDF and every attempt to get a more detailed error log failed.

You can find my PDF here: https://pastebin.com/tTTxaz8z

I hope anyone could help me.

Comment: Please share PDFs as binary downloads, not as text. Text transfer is subject to changes in encoding and control characters.

Comment: This PDF is safe to be transmitted via pastebin.
I didn't modified the PDF by hand, I generated it using a self writtan program, as I said. As far as I can tell, my byte addresses are correct, but If you can correct me, that would be great

Comment: Are you sure about this? Because before I've added the metadata part everything worked fine.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I assumed that the index bytes were correct, but I've added Unicode characters, so I had double byte characters, which corrupted my calculations. You were right the whole time, sorry. Btw, which program did you use to validate the PDF?

Comment: When dealing with xref positions or xref table issues, a hex editor usually is all you need.